# How to transpose the data frame to generate an excel file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have been working on something where I am extracting information from the word document and storing it in a dataframe, and then converting them into an excel file. I got that functionality right, but now I want to transpose the excel file which is being generated. Below is the code I have come up with

```
from docx import Document
import pandas as pd

def extract_text_from_docx(docx_path, keywords):
    doc = Document(docx_path)
    extracted_data = []
    
    # Check if the document contains tables
    for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
        text = paragraph.text
        for keyword in keywords:
            if keyword in text:
                before_keyword, after_keyword = text.split(keyword, 1)
                extracted_data.append((keyword, after_keyword.strip()))
                break
    
    # Extract data from tables
    for table in doc.tables:
        for row in table.rows:
            key_cell, value_cell = row.cells[:2]  # Assuming each row contains at least two cells
            key = key_cell.text.strip()
            value = value_cell.text.strip()
            if key in keywords:
                extracted_data.append((key, value))

    return extracted_data

def generate_excel_from_data(data, selected_keys, output_file):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Keyword', 'Value'])
    filtered_df = df[df['Keyword'].isin(selected_keys)]
    transposed_df = filtered_df.pivot(index=None, columns='Keyword', values='Value')
    
    # Transpose the DataFrame
    transposed_df = transposed_df.T.reset_index(drop=True)
    
    transposed_df.to_excel(output_file, index=False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    docx_path = '/Users/apple/Documents/test1.docx'
    keywords = ['Candidate name', 'Position applied for', 'Current location', 'Current employer', 'Total-experience', 'Total CTC', 'Expected CTC', 'Notice period (also if there is an option to buy-out)', 'Willingness to relocate with FAMILY – at the time of joining itself', 'Assessment Comments by HRINPUTS', 'Remarks']  # List of keywords
    selected_keys = ['Candidate name', 'Position applied for', 'Current location', 'Current employer', 'Total-experience', 'Total CTC', 'Expected CTC', 'Notice period (also if there is an option to buy-out)', 'Willingness to relocate with FAMILY – at the time of joining itself', 'Assessment Comments by HRINPUTS', 'Remarks'] # List of selected keys
    output_file = 'selected_key_value_pairs1.xlsx'
    
    # Extract text from Word document and store it in a list of tuples
    extracted_data = extract_text_from_docx(docx_path, keywords)

    # Generate Excel file with selected key-value pairs
    generate_excel_from_data(extracted_data, selected_keys, output_file)
```

These are the errors I am receiving when I execute the file

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/apple/Desktop/HRinputs/test.py", line 49, in <module>
    generate_excel_from_data(extracted_data, selected_keys, output_file)
  File "/Users/apple/Desktop/HRinputs/test.py", line 31, in generate_excel_from_data
    transposed_df = filtered_df.pivot(index=None, columns='Keyword', values='Value')
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 9025, in pivot
    return pivot(self, index=index, columns=columns, values=values)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/pivot.py", line 536, in pivot
    index_list = [data[idx] for idx in com.convert_to_list_like(index)]
                  ~~~~^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3893, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3798, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting an error because you set the `index` to `None`. You can try these ones I believe,

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Keyword', 'Value'])
filtered_df = df[df['Keyword'].isin(selected_keys)]

transposed_df = filtered_df.set_index('Keyword').T
```

or use [transpose](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) directly,

```py
transposed_df = filtered_df.transpose()
```